# Python - возможен ли "плавающий" срез?

Tags: python

Всем привет!
Есть список y=[1,2,3,4,5]. Нужно рассчитать среднее списка после последовательного удаления каждого из элементов списка, то есть:  y=[2,3,4,5], потом y=[1,3,4,5], y=[1,2,3,5] и т.д.
Так как со срезами не получилось, то на ум пришел вариант удалять "ненужный" элемент, а после расчет возвращать его обратно.
Код получился рабочий, но остались сомнения - может все-таки можно как-то красивей его сделать?

```
import numpy as np
y=[1,2,3,4,5]
mean=[]
for i in range(0,len(y)):
    a=y.pop(i)
    mean.append(np.mean(y))
    y.insert(0,a)
print(mean)
```

Answer (score 6):

Надо ли в этой задаче работать со срезами? Нет. `<Среднее среза> = <сумма среза> / <длина среза>`, `<сумма среза> = <сумма массива> - <значение одного элемента>`, `<длина среза> = <длина массива> - 1`:

```
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

s = sum(y)
print([(s - v) / (len(y) - 1) for v in y])
```

Так как мы работаем с `numpy`, можно всё записать в виде одного выражения:

```
import numpy as np


y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

print((np.sum(y) - y) / (len(y) - 1))
```

Посмотрите как `numpy` правильно вычисляет `(<число> - <массив>) / <число>`. Всё работает как ожидается благодаря [броадкастингу](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

Answer (score 2):

Можно сложить два среза - до текущего элемента и после:

```py
import numpy as np

y=[1,2,3,4,5]
mean=[]
for i in range(0,len(y)):
    mean.append(np.mean(y[:i]+y[i+1:]))
print(mean)
# [3.5, 3.25, 3.0, 2.75, 2.5]
```

Для длинных списков это будет не очень хорошо, но можно использовать другой вариант - посчитать сумму массива заранее, вычитать по очереди из неё текущий элемент и считать самому среднее:

```py
import numpy as np

y=[1,2,3,4,5]
mean=[]
sum_y = np.sum(y)
len_y_m1 = len(y) - 1
for i in range(0,len(y)):
    mean.append((sum_y - y[i])/len_y_m1)
print(mean)
# [3.5, 3.25, 3.0, 2.75, 2.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Не понятно, почему у вас со срезами не получилось"...

```
import numpy as np
y=[1,2,3,4,5]
means=[]
for i in range(len(y)-1):
    means.append(np.mean(y[i:]))
    
print(means)
```

> [3.0, 3.5, 4.0, 4.5]

Comment: Ответов должно быть пять. У вас - четыре.

Answer (score 1):

```
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

l = len(y)
x = [(sum(y) - y[i]) / (l - 1) for i in range(l)]

# [3.5, 3.25, 3.0, 2.75, 2.5]
```

Comment: Почему вы оптимизируете `len` (дешёвый) и заново считаете `sum` (дорогой) ?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy. И вот не поспоришь. ))) Есть косяк. Спасибо